# Why am i getting "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison" error on this Python Binary Search?

Tags: python, binary-search

I wrote this Binary Search as a task for my Uni:

```
def bin_search(l,i,start,end):
    if start >= end:
        return False
    else:
        pos = (start + end) // 2
        if i == l[pos]:
            return True
        elif i < l[pos]:
            return bin_search(l,i,start,pos)
        else:
            return bin_search(l,i,pos,end)
```

I keep getting a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison` error message.
If i change the last line to:

```
         return bin_search(l,i,pos + 1,end)
```

it does not happen, I do not understand why this is because as I understood it in the not working code the same range of the list plus one more should be given as a parameter.
Can you please tell me where my mistake is.

Comment: `bin_search(l,i,start,pos - 1)` and `bin_search(l,i,pos + 1, end)`

Comment: Add `print(start, end)` right after your `def` line, and you'll see your error immediately,

Comment: @avysk thank you that did explain my mistake for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def bin_search(l,i,start = 0,end):
    if start >= end:
        return False
    else:
        pos = (start + end) // 2
        if i == l[pos]:
            return True
        elif i < l[pos]:
            return bin_search(l,i,start + 1,pos)
        else:
            return bin_search(l,i,pos + 1,end)
```

Comment: worth to mention that even if the code would look correct, default recursion level would still be exceeded if the list of values to be search is greater than what `sys.getrecursionlimit()` will return (which is afaik 1000 by default)

Comment: thanx for the atention.